# Button click help (Greasemonkey)

Tags: javascript, button, click, greasemonkey

Please help me, I need to click these 2 <strike>buttons</strike> links:

```
<li class="booster" id="b_10">
    <img alt="" src="http://www.erepublik.com/images/parts/pixel.gif" class="overlay" />
    <div class="top">
        <strong><a href="javascript:;">Army boots</a></strong>
        <big>0</big>
    </div>
    <img src="http://static.erepublik.com/uploads/boosters/10_77x77.png" alt="" />
    <em class="give like10"></em>
</li>
```

And:

```
<span class="tip" id="tip_534689">
    <a class="workTrigger" companyId="534689" href="javascript:;">
        <img src="http://www.erepublik.com/images/modules/myland/tip_icons/work.png" alt="" />
    </a>
</span>
```

Comment: For so little code, do not link to it at an external site that might disappear in the future!  Also, we need the full page code to help with choosing selectors to pick the right node(s).  So post ***that*** code to mibpaste.com, pastebin.com, etc.  (Or -- better yet -- link to the page if we can see it without undue registration.)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work, but the `// @include` directive should be more specific, if possible, and the jQuery selectors might require information that was not given in the question.

The art is in choosing the selectors to get the link/button/node you are after.  For best results, this often requires seeing the whole page's code.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name            _Generic Link clicker
// @include         http://www.erepublik.com/*
// @require         http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

var topBoosterLink  = $("li.booster > div.top > strong > a:first");
var workTipLink     = $("span.tip > a.workTrigger:first");

clickJ_Node (topBoosterLink);
clickJ_Node (workTipLink);


function clickJ_Node (jNode)
{
    if (jNode && jNode.length)
    {
        var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ("HTMLEvents");
        clickEvent.initEvent ("click", true, true);
        jNode[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
    }
    else
        GM_log ('No node found to click!');
}
```

Comment: as you predicted, it's not working. The full page source for the first link is http://pastebin.com/bRDFmh8Z , and for the second link is http://pastebin.com/RA1v8Jyz .

Comment: @user796738, using the pastebin code, I've verified that the answer-script *does* click the appropriate link (tested 1st link only).  **However**, there are several things going on with that page.  First, does clicking "Army boots" merely set its checkbox?  And the script does not do that?  How *exactly* does it "not work"?   Second, the page captures all kinds of mouse events on those "buttons", and has an image overly to boot.  It may be that a sequence of events is needed.  They may have taken steps to obstruct this kind of scripting.